# How to change the bounding box linewidth of a plot in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am getting trouble in finding example of changing `linewidth` of the boundary box of a plot in Python plot.

For example, `fig=plt.figure(figsize=(4.5, 4))` this command gives the dimension of the box in which python will plot the graph. But how to increase the `linewidth` of this boundary?

Comment: Maybe have a look at the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html)?   `plt.figure(..., edgecolor='black', linewidth=3)` ?

Answer (score 2):

There are few options to do this depending on which boundary you are talking about.

**Window.** `fig=plt.figure(figsize=(4.5, 4))` command embeds figure in window which is controlled by system. It's quite hard to find any solution here unless it's a hack. The only accessible option is to use `root.overrideredirect(True)` here:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4.5, 4))
ax = fig.gca()
mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mng.window.overrideredirect(True)
plt.show()
```

**Figure.**
Another option is to change border of `matplotlib.pyplot.figure`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4.5, 4), edgecolor='blue', linewidth=3)
ax = fig.gca()
plt.show()
```

**Axis.**

If the option is to change width of `matplotlib.pyplot.axis`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4.5, 4))
ax = fig.gca()
for axis in ['top','bottom','left','right']:
    ax.spines[axis].set_linewidth(0.5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Many Thanks for your answers. It really helps. Here, I would like to add how I solved the problem in the mean time.   I added two lines in the python code:    from pylab import * ; then rc('axes', linewidth=2) . It worked for me. Thanks anyway.